# Apex batch - Use Map values on the start method instead of running Database.Querylocator with a SOQL query

Tags: batch

I have a batch class that accepts a map as an input paramter on the batch constructor. I want to use the map values to be passed into the execute method in batches instead of running a query with Database.querylocator(). The below is what I have tried

```
global class batchClass implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful { 
    public Map<Id, Custom_Object__c> mapValues;
   
    global batchClass(Map<Id, Custom_Object__c> mapSet) {
        this.mapValues = mapSet;
    }
    global List<SObject> start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        return mapValues.values();
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<SObject> scope){
        //I want to retrieve the values of the map in batches to do some processing here
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {}
}
```

I get this error when deploying the above code - Class must implement the method: System.Iterable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Iterable instead of List:

```
public Iterable<SObject> start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    return mapValues.values();
}
```

Note that batch classes do not need to be global in order to save.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox for a speedy response